# C++ class with private global kernel methods

Tags: c++, class, cuda, global

In relation to another problem I was experiencing with linking and multiple defined functions, I wanted to simply wrap my cuda code in a singleton class.

Something along

```
class Singleton{
public:
  __host__ void doSomething();
private:
  __global__ void someKernel();
};
```

That apparently only **device** methods may be used and the above gives "invalid combination of memory qualifiers". I would like to wrap my code in a class to get more structured code, but if I need to place every kernel externally, it makes little sense.

The same question has been posed previously on nvidias site, but without an answer
http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=176623

I too understand the problem with the this pointer, but even a static method cannot be global.

Comment: Is there really a question here? The CUDA language doesn't allow `__global__` declarations inside classes, mostly for the same reasons that kernels can't call kernels and external linkage isn't supported. Neither the toolchain nor the hardware can do what would be required to support any of those things.

Comment: Classes are bad choice though they look elegant. Go ahead with static methods or global functions which can help you in calling the object and it's function. Thus you can maintain the state as well(if it's required)

Answer (score 1):

If you want calling code to look more organized, you could probably call your kernel from a method, if it helps.

Comment: Yes a static member should be fine. I intended to pass various device pointers along to the kernel through arguments anyway.

Comment: I actually hadn't seen the last line in your question, so my answer becomes useless. Sorry about that.

Comment: wrote " call your kernel from a method". Come to think about it, having a static kernel method in the class or having a kernel function outside the class makes _very little_ difference when using the c++ way of defining a class in a h file and implementing it in a cpp file, or a cu file.